# Unable to resolve a dependency on URLUtil, conflicting requirements

Tags: java, maven

I'm getting the following error when trying to compile my project:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/httpclient/util/URIUtil
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.URLFileName.getPathQueryEncoded(URLFileName.java:91)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.URLFileName.getURIEncoded(URLFileName.java:161)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.url.UrlFileObject.createURL(UrlFileObject.java:74)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.url.UrlFileObject.doAttach(UrlFileObject.java:63)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.AbstractFileObject.attach(AbstractFileObject.java:1505)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.AbstractFileObject.getType(AbstractFileObject.java:489)
    .... (More project-scope traces)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.httpclient.util.URIUtil
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 13 more
```

I have the following maven dependencies in my project, among others:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-vfs2</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

I absolutely *must* depend on a HttpClient version 4.3.4 or greater because of other dependencies and various bugs we ran into with previous versions. After a bit of research, I discovered the class in question (URLUtil) was removed from HttpClient after HttpClient 3.1.

Is there any way to resolve this? Or another library I could use instead of vfs2? I'm attempting to write files over sftp using both user/pass and key authentication schemes.

Comment: You should tell us why "I absolutely must depend on a HttpClient version 4.3.4 or greater."

Comment: Added a little clarification. This library has been a headache in particular, we finally found a version that works with all of our other dependencies and doesn't have crippling bugs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out, the artifacts are different between the 3.x and 4.x releases of HttpClient. All I had to do was include:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Silly me, thinking that they'd override each-other.